# "Content Security Policy of your site blocks the use of 'eval' in JavaScript" warning when setting CSP meta tag in Electron

Tags: javascript, electron, google-chrome-devtools, content-security-policy

I am creating an Electron application, and per the [Electron security tutorial](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/security#csp-meta-tag) I have added a CSP meta tag. When running the application, this issue appears in devtools.

> **Content Security Policy of your site blocks the use of 'eval' in JavaScript**
> The Content Security Policy (CSP) prevents the evaluation of arbitrary strings as JavaScript to make it more difficult for an attacker to inject unauthorized code on your site.
> To solve this issue, avoid using `eval()`, `new Function()`, `setTimeout([string], ...)` and `setInterval([string], ...)` for evaluating strings.

No `eval` calls or other cases of string evaluation are present in my own code. The issue does not give any clue as to what code is causing it, and my attempts to use the `'report-sample'` value had no effect on output. The issue does not appear when opening the HTML file in Chrome.

I can recreate the warning with a very basic application.

#### main.js

```
const path = require("path");
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require("electron");

const createWindow = () => {
  let mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      contextIsolation: true,
      nodeIntegration: false,
    }
  });

  mainWindow.loadURL(`file://${path.join(__dirname, "/index.html")}`);
};

app.on("ready", createWindow);
```

#### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>CSP Issue Test</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

I would like to understand why this issue is appearing and resolve it rather than just suppress the warning.

Comment: I guess that warning must be generated by Electron. But anyway, it's not saying you have any eval() instances in your code. Instead, it's just saying that, because it's served with a CSP header that disallows eval(), you will not be able to add any code that uses eval(). If you did actually have any instances of eval() in your code, the browser would be logging a CSP error in the devtools console.

Comment: can you try `loadFile` instead of `loadRUL`? The error doesnt hint at this but I would still try it for some reason.  `mainWindow.loadFile('index.html')`

Comment: I think Chrome has a problem - they're misinterpreting the CSP and their message warning is pointless. By default 'eval' is disallowed by the browser, you don't have to explicitly say so in the CSP. If you wish to enable 'eval' you use 'unsafe-eval' in the CSP. Hopefully Chrome will do away with this pointless message. What they should be doing is warning you if you are using 'unsafe-eval'.

Comment: I suspect that the hiccup is introduced in the string enclosed by backticks (looks like an `eval()` in disguise to me). Maybe you should, instead of having `path.join(__dirname, "/index.html")` evaluated within the string, append it to `file://` (as in `"file://" + path.join(__dirname, "/index.html")`). See if the problem goes away after this modification.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the Electron Github repo's [issues](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/26973), "This log message is currently expected in development, if you run your packaged app it will not occur." This is according to one of the Electron contributors.

This issue is closed now but it's still active and some users are saying it is a bit confusing (I agree). Based on this, I think we just ignore it during development. It should go away when the app is packaged according to the contributor though I myself have not tested this out.

Comment: "You should just ignore it" is an amazingly short-sighted response from the electron devs, and a great way to condition electron users into unintentionally introducing a whole host of actual security issues into their future products...

Comment: Yeah, I have the same exact sentiments. I honestly had a hard time "just ignoring it" too because every time I debug my application I'd see that. It's dangerous because, as you've said, when a real (God forbid dangerous) bug enters the app, you might not notice it ://

Comment: The problem is, it's the backticks that cause the CSP hiccup. You can reproduce this with vanilla JS (you don't even need Electron for this).

Answer (score -3):

As of version 5, the default for nodeIntegration changed from true to false. You can enable it when creating the Browser Window:

```
   app.on('ready', () => {
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true,
            contextIsolation: false,
        }
    });
});
```

And Remove this from html

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'">
```

Comment: this is potentially quite dangerous, and won't solve the issue at hand – disabling `nodeIntegration` and enabling `contextIsolation` are useful steps to take to improve the security of an electron app.

Comment: But, this warning has nothing to do with `nodeIntegration`. Having Node integration can still be safe if you don't run any unsafe scripts (assuming you trust yourself to not write bugs :D), but anyway this is not the point. The OP has no `eval` and has opted in on a security feature, why is this viewed as an "issue"? It only increases security; perhaps I am interpreting "issue" wrong?

Comment: This won't solve the actual problem which is introduced by executing JavaScript in a backticked string...